# Do distance selling protection regulations work across borders?

Tags: united-kingdom, ecommerce, online-payment, consumer-protection

When buying online in the UK, purchases are covered by the [distance selling regulations](http://www.opsi.gov.uk/si/si2000/20002334.htm), which basically give you 14 days to return or annul an agreement or purchase made online.

If I buy products from a company based in another country am I still covered, or do the regulations in effect in the vendor's country take precedence?

Answer (score 3):

It's a different and complicated set of laws.  In the EU, there is a thing called the EU Distance Selling Directive, which is an effort at creating a minimum set of regulations, which should give you a minimum return period (I don't know how long) for anything bought in the EU.